# Docker push in Jenkins - denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Tags: docker, jenkins, jenkins-pipeline

So I'm trying to set up a pipeline in Jenkins to build image and push them to Docker hub.
My credentials in Manage 'Jenkins' are called the same as "docker-hub-credentials" and seem to be used.

It can build, but it just doesn't get through the push... Help? I've been on that for hours and I'm not sure what I' missing.

I've already tried using docker login, but jenkins doesn't allow it.

```
stage('Build image') {
    /* This builds the actual image; synonymous to
     * docker build on the command line */

     bat 'docker build -t username/foldername:build . '    }


stage('Push image') {
    /* Finally, we'll push the image with two tags:
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry.hub.docker.com', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
        bat 'docker push username/foldername:build'
    }
}
```

I expect the image to be pushed, but I have this instead :

```
The push refers to repository [docker.io/username/foldername]
a73d7d9f4346: Preparing
964bdfb24a54: Preparing
1af124d739c9: Preparing
6cffeea81e5d: Preparing
614a79865f6d: Preparing
612d27bb923f: Preparing
ef68f6734aa4: Preparing
612d27bb923f: Waiting
ef68f6734aa4: Waiting
denied: requested access to the resource is denied
```

Comment: You may to need to use `docker login`

Comment: I can't do docker login, it's not interactive :/

Comment: Try `docker-login` on the machine that this will run on ? Or does the machine change from time to time?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I found the answer!!!

```
 stage('Push image') {
        withDockerRegistry([ credentialsId: "docker-hub-credentials", url: "" ]) {
        bat "docker push devopsglobalmedia/teamcitydocker:build"
        }
```

Comment: or `docker.withRegistry('', 'docker-hub-credentials') { ... `

Comment: You saved my life, what an incredible waste of time with this error.

Answer (score 4):

In `Image push` stage, you can do `docker login` first and then push the image. Try the following for docker login:

```
stage('Push image') {
    withCredentials([usernamePassword( credentialsId: 'docker-hub-credentials', usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD')]) {
        def registry_url = "registry.hub.docker.com/"
        bat "docker login -u $USER -p $PASSWORD ${registry_url}"
        docker.withRegistry("http://${registry_url}", "docker-hub-credentials") {
            // Push your image now
            bat "docker push username/foldername:build"
        }
    }
}
```

Make sure the registry url is correct.
`withCredentials([usernamePassword(...)])` method above will set two environment variables `USER` and `PASSWORD` which are your docker registry credentials from credentials id `docker-hub-credentials`.

Comment: But isn't that harcoding my password...?

Comment: No, You aren't hardcoding the password. Create a username/password credential in Jenkins named "docker-hub-credentials". If that's already done, the code I suggested should work. Have a look at the function https://jenkins.io/doc/pipeline/steps/credentials-binding/#withcredentials-bind-credentials-to-variables , used the code

Comment: Oh, so you mean to actually not replace usernameVariable: 'USER', passwordVariable: 'PASSWORD' with the actual credentials? They already are in the Credentials, and I don't them in my file.

Comment: Something I am worried as well is : I don't want my password in the logs

Comment: Any credentials you get using function `withCredentials` method can't be exposed in plain. Even if you try to print it in logs, it would just print asterisk ( ******* ).

Comment: Thanks a lot, I literally copied pasted what you wrote and added my docker push with right names, but I still hit denied/refused...

Comment: I tried with --password-stdin registry.hub.docker.com/ but obviously :
Error: Cannot perform an interactive login from a non TTY device

Answer (score 1):

A better option is to use [Docker pipeline plugin](https://jenkins.io/doc/book/pipeline/docker/) (it comes in the recommended plugins).

```
node {

  checkout scm
  def dockerImage

  stage('Build image') {
    dockerImage = docker.build("username/repository:tag")
  }

  stage('Push image') {
    dockerImage.push()
  }   

}
```

Doing it this way, you must specify the credentials of the docker registry in the **Pipeline Model Definition**.

Docker pipeline plugin has problems applying the credentials assigned in Pipeline Model Definition to projects with Multi-branch pipeline. That is, if using the above code you continue to receive the error:

> denied: requested access to the resource is denied

Then you must specify the credentials in the Jenkinsfile as follows:

```
node {

  checkout scm
  def dockerImage

  stage('Build image') {
    dockerImage = docker.build("username/repository:tag")
  }

  stage('Push image') {
    docker.withRegistry('https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
      dockerImage.push()
    }
  }

}
```

You can modify the URL to a custom registry if you need it

Comment: Hello! thanks for your answer. I went for a "manual" build with the plugin but I do want a pipeline so i followed your advice. Two things happened: It doesn't accept dockerImage = docker.build as it says there is no nohup (I'm using Windows env) so i changed to docker image = bat 'docker build -t username/image:build .'. Secondly, in the stage push image, it doesn't want to work with dockerImage as it seems it is null...? But the image is successfully built... Any idea?

Comment: Hello again! I have tried docker.withRegistry('https://registry-1.docker.io/v2/', 'docker-hub-credentials') {
        bat "docker push devopsglobalmedia/teamcitydocker:build" and this time, it just tells me "denied: requested access to the resource is denied
"

Comment: Hi! I don't think dockerImage = bat 'docker build...' should work. I run Jenkins on Docker, i've never worked with Jenkins running natively on Windows, I'm sorry I can't help you. I hope you can find a solution.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue recently, it was a wrong the docker registry url

The issue - `https://index.docker.io/v1`

The fix - `https://index.docker.io/v1/`

Yep, it was an issue. I was not able to push it to docker registry.

Answer (score 0):

I have spent like half days to solve it. Please make sure `Docker Pipeline Plugin` installed.

```
script {
  withDockerRegistry([ credentialsId: "Docker-Hub-Cred", url: "https://index.docker.io/v1/" ]){            
                             
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to push private repository then below commands you have to follow:

1st: you have to make sure dockerhub credentials on jenkins.
2nd: You have creat a job with pipeline project
3rd: Then you have to push your project with jenkinsfile.
4th: now you can build jenkins.

I am giving full Jenkinsfile it will help to solve this permission denied problem and successfully u can create docker image and push to dockerhub.

```html
pipeline {
     agent any
     stages{
        stage('Maven Install'){
                      agent any
                      steps{
                          bat 'mvn -f pom.xml clean install'
                      }
                  }

        stage('Docker Build'){
                         agent any
                         steps{
                             bat 'docker build -t dockerhub_username/repository_name/docker-jenkins-integration .'
                         }
                     }

        stage('Push image'){
                    agent any
                    steps{
                      
                        
                                       withDockerRegistry([ credentialsId: "id", url: "" ]) {
                                       bat "docker tag dockerhub_username/repository_name/docker-jenkins-integration dockerhub_username/repository_name:docker-jenkins-integration"
                                       bat "docker push dockerhub_username/repository_name:docker-jenkins-integration"
                                     }

                }


                }
     }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

As of today, Docker pipeline plugin gives groovy methods to login to docker hub, build image and finally push it.
Below is a sample code for a declarative pipeline

```
pipeline {
agent any
stages {
    stage('Push container') {
        steps {
            echo "Workspace is $WORKSPACE"
            dir("$WORKSPACE/dir-to-Dockerfile") {
                script {
                    def REGISTRY_URL = "https://index.docker.io/v1/"
                    def USER_NAME = "your-registry-username"
                    docker.withRegistry("$REGISTRY_URL", 'DockerHub-Cred-ID-Defined-In-Jenkins') {
                        def image = docker.build("$USER_NAME/some-image-name:${env.BUILD_ID}")
                        image.push()
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0):

I solved by add :

```
stage('Push Docker Image') {
            steps {
                withDockerRegistry([credentialsId: "docker_auth", url: "https://index.docker.io/v1/"]) {
                    bat "docker push IMAGE_NAME:latest"
                }
            }
        }
```

Answer (score 0):

```
withCredentials([usernamePassword(credentialsId: 'somewhat', passwordVariable: 'PASS', usernameVariable: 'USER')]) {
           "echo $PASS | docker login -u $USER --password-stdin"
        }
```

Hello, I suggest more convenient and secure way to pass password as it written in docker documentation, by using `stdin`,it prevents the password from ending up in the shell’s history, or `log-files`. Good luck ;)